# send data from file to file in express

Tags: node.js, express

so what I want to do is sending an string which is a path for my image .. I want to do that in routes file . because I receive in it the image path like that

```
const imageReko = require("./image-Reko");

if(req.body.act === "post") {
    if(req.body.img){
      imageReko(req.body.img)
    }
    const post = new Post({
      
        content: req.body.content,
        firstName:req.body.firstName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName, 
        img: req.body.img,

    });
```

so what I have done is export all my image recognition file like that

```
const imageReko = () =>{
 const photo  = 'image2.jpg' // i want to put my string that i have passed it from my route files
// somecode
}
```

I described in comment what I want to do ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you want to get a string from the request body then pass it into a function in `./image-Reko` which will store it in a variable.

### Function Parameters

First of all the function in `image-Reko` has no parameters. This means when you pass `req.body.img` the function will ignore it since it cannot use it. To fix this you need to add a parameter to the function like so:

```
const imageRecko = (img) => {
   // Code here
}
```

### const vs. var and let

In the function you defined a variable called `photo` with the keyword `const` which declares a constant variable. This variable can not be re declared or redefined so you can change this variable with your function. To fix this:

```
const imageReko = (img) => {
   var photo = img;
}
```

This way you can assign the variable inside the function.

This is what i understood from your question let me know if i missed something. Good luck with your project!

Comment: good .. so i have question can i await the data that is coming from that file or no ?

Comment: I don't understand the question since you're not getting or sending any files anywhere. Is there more code where you deal with fiels?

Answer (score 0):

Since you pass `req.body.img` as parameter for `imageReko()` you can use it in the `imageReko` function

```
const imageReko = (img) =>{
 const photo  = img
// somecode
}
```